# Return json on Angular Response

Tags: angular

How can I response a json from an http request  in Angular 10 I cant find `Response` and in `HttpResponse`I can't find a function called json (I'm new on Angular)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient,HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class JsonService {

  constructor( private http:HttpClient) { }

  getData():Observable<any>{
    let url = '';
    return this.http.get('https://gorest.co.in/public-api/users');//I want to return json here 
  }
}
```

Comment: `HttpClient` automatically parses the response as JSON. You do not need to do anything extra in the consumer of `getData` to transform the response to JSON other than `subscribe()` or with `async` pipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can try this

```
  getData():Observable<any>{
    let url = '';
    return this.http.get('https://gorest.co.in/public-api/users').pipe(
      map((data)=>{
        // Your json data
        console.log(data)
      }),
      catchError(err => { return throwError(err) })
    )
  }
```

Note: never forget catch error